# Synchronization problems with automated testing Angular website with Selenium and testing issues with Internet Explorer.

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, internet-explorer, automated-tests

I am trying to write an automated test program for one of my website using Selenium WEbDriver. I am having some problems when doing the test on Internet Explorer. The website that I am trying to test is built in AngularJS. I will explain my problems in detail.

Here, is the code that waits until Angular has finished processing.

```
private static ExpectedCondition angularHasFinishedProcessing() {
    return (ExpectedCondition<Boolean>) driver -> {
        String hasAngularFinishedScript = "var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];\n" +
                "var el = document.querySelector('html');\n" +
                "if (!window.angular) {\n" +
                "    callback('false')\n" +
                "}\n" +
                "if (angular.getTestability) {\n" +
                "    angular.getTestability(el).whenStable(function(){callback('true')});\n" +
                "} else {\n" +
                "    if (!angular.element(el).injector()) {\n" +
                "        callback('false')\n" +
                "    }\n" +
                "    var browser = angular.element(el).injector().get('$browser');\n" +
                "    browser.notifyWhenNoOutstandingRequests(function(){callback('true')});\n" +
                "}";

        JavascriptExecutor javascriptExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        assert javascriptExecutor != null;
        String isProcessingFinished = javascriptExecutor.executeAsyncScript(hasAngularFinishedScript).toString();

        return Boolean.valueOf(isProcessingFinished);
    };
}

private void waitForAngular() {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15, 100);
    wait.until(angularHasFinishedProcessing());
}
```

And here is the code that instantiates WebDriver for Internet Explorer.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver",
    new File("H:/libraries/webdrivers/IEDriverServer.exe").getAbsolutePath());
DesiredCapabilities d = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
// To bypasse the Protected Mode settings of IE
d.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(d);
driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("https://arandomangularjsapp.com"); // Let's suppose this
```

I had to bypass the Protected Mode settings (shown in above code) because I was constantly getting this Exception

```
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unexpected error launching Internet
Explorer. Protected Mode must be set to the same value (enabled or disabled) for all
zones. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

though I made sure that protected mode was enabled and same values were set for all zones.

Now comes the real issue I am having. Look at this block of code,

```
waitForAngular();

WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='events-list__event-info' and @id='48040']" +
            "//following-sibling::div[@class='events-list__event-buy']/a"));
if(driver.toString().toUpperCase().contains("INTERNETEXPLORER"))
    el.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
else
    el.click();

waitForAngular();

webElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@class='ticket u-cf ng-scope'])[1]//select"));
select = new Select(webElement);
select.selectByIndex(1);
```

**My first question, the way I am trying to wait for Angular app to get ready by calling `waitForAngular()`, is it a good way?** In my program I even had to use `Thread.sleep()` so many times in order to let elements to properly render before I could invoke actions on them. It would be great if you guys can suggest me a proper way to use Selenium WebDriver along with Angular App.

Now let's talk about my second issue. I had to completely disable Protected Mode from Internet Explorer's options in order to run the program. Otherwise, I would get this exception,

```
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: JavaScript error in async script. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

I get this exception when trying to execute `waitForAngular()`. **What could be causing this? Is there any way by which I could keep the Protected Mode enabled and still be able to execute that script inside `angularHasFinishedProcessing()` method?**

Finally, my third problem is related to click action not being triggered. Forget about the previous issues for a second. I disabled IE's Protected Mode, so my program starts IE without throwing any exception. The program successfully finds the first element as shown in the code above. But, the click action is not triggered, browser thus doesn't navigate to next page, and the program fails to find the second element. As a workaround I even tried `el.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);` but it didn't work.** So, am I having this problem because I bypassed/disabled Protected Mode? Or, is there something else that I am not being able to see?**

I run tests on IE, Opera, Chrome and Firefox and the problem seems to occur only in IE. Any sort of help, suggestions or guidelines are highly appreciated.

Thank You.